Sagotra marriage after adoption
Can two get married from same gotra (sagotra), if the girl or the bit is adopted by someone else belonging to another gotra?
For instance, I heard a situation where boy and girl are in love, and ready to get married. Bride's parents have her away in adoption to someone in their relative, belonging to different gotra. Then wedding was concluded.
Is this adoption an alternative?
What are the rules for adoption? Is there any age limit for that?
After adoption, the child gets adopted parent's gotra?
